# Deleting a bot message after a while?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My bot welcomes new members, how do I delete the message after a while?

My code for the hello message:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
    await channel.send(f'Hello')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `delete_after` kwarg.
For example `await channel.send(f'Hello', delete_after=60)`

Comment: please tell me, and it is possible to display to the user how much time is left in real time.  Using the countdown as an example ?